# Sphinx Search binlog format is not backward compatible?

Tags: sphinx

Question to Sphinx team: Why in new 2.0.5 release binlog format is not compatible with previous 2.0.4 version?

How can I migrate to new version?

See what I have got after I installed 2.0.5:

```
WARNING: index 'index_9127': preload: /var/db/sphinxsearch/idx/index_9127.meta is v.6, binary is v.5; NOT SERVING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *IS* compatible.

I've investigated our source and found that there is NO VERSION CHANGES
between 2.0.4 and 2.0.5 (as it actually must be).

The version of binlog was changed, however, in our trunk (which is
2.1-dev branch, NOT 2.0.X!) In the trunk we are free to bump versions up
since we add new functionality and develop the sphinx. Since the svn
rev. numbering is one for both branches, it is important to hold
necessary branch when using the sphinx built from svn. For example, svn
rev 3308 is in rel20 branch and is 2.0.5-release, however the svn rev
3189 is in the trunk branch and is current 2.1.X-dev. Here the more
number (3308 against 3189) by no way says that the higher one points to
more 'fresh' version. They can't be confused, by the way, since they are
placed in different branches (=folders) in svn repo.

Actually it seems that you use the 'trunk' version (2.1.X-dev), and then
upgraded to 2.0.5 (and actually it was donwgrade, NOT upgrade). And,
what is consequent - the old version of sphinx couldn't load the fresh
version of index.

So, the problem is *NOT* in the sphinx at all.

If the data is important, and if downgrade into 2.0.5 branch is also
important, it may have sence to shut down the sphinx properly (this way
the binlog will contain no data, since it's purpose is to hold crashes),
and then wipe out all binlog files, include 'meta'. After restarting,
the sphinx will recreate the files with current version.
However - it need to be performed with backup - since apart the meta
version change it might be also another changes in the index format (and
if so, the older version anyway will not load the fresher index).

BTW it is ok to stay in 2.1-dev, since the whole content of stable 2.0.X
branch is periodically merged into the trunk, so the all bugs there will
be also fixed in the trunk.